# merge two different types of RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Hi guys i would like to combine an RDD[Vector] and RDD[Int] to RDD[Vector]
this what i did , i have use Kmeans to predict cluster , the idea is to add in front each vector the correspondant cluster .Here what i did

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
val data = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:/spark/data/mllib/kmeans_data.txt")
 //Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
val numClusters = 2
val numIterations = 20
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()//RDD[vector]
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)
val resultatOfprediction=clusters.predict(parsedData)//RDD[int]
val finalData=parsedData.zip(resultatOfprediction)
finalData.collect().foreach(println)
```

the result is

```
([0.0,0.0,0.0],0)
([0.1,0.1,0.1],0)
([0.2,0.2,0.2],0)
([9.0,9.0,9.0],1)
([9.1,9.1,9.1],1)
([9.2,9.2,9.2],1)
```

the output i would like

```
    [0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
    [0.1,0.1,0.1,1.0]
    [0.2,0.2,0.2,1.0]
    [9.0,9.0,9.0,0.0]
    [9.1,9.1,9.1,0.0]
    [9.2,9.2,9.2,0.0]
```

the goal is that i want to save aa final RDD[vector]into a txt file to display it in a grid.but the result you provide isnot an RDD[vector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the result you wanted you need to zip these two RDD. Here is how you do it

```
val parsedData = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0))

val resultatOfprediction = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  (0.0,0.0,0.0),
  (0.1,0.1,0.1),
  (0.2,0.2,0.2),
  (9.0,9.0,9.0),
  (9.1,9.1,9.1),
  (9.2,9.2,9.2)
))

resultatOfprediction.zip(parsedData)
```

Since it returns a tuple you can get result as

```
resultatOfprediction.zip(parsedData)
      .map(t => (t._1._1, t._1._2, t._1._3, t._2))
```

For dynamic you can do as folling as sugested by @Rahul-Sukla  `resultatOfprediction.zip(parsedData) .map(t => t._1.productIterator.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double]) :+ t._2)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: i did not get a correct answer , please would you provide an other answer thanks

Comment: Isn't this is your output (0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
(0.1,0.1,0.1,1.0)
(0.2,0.2,0.2,1.0)
(9.0,9.0,9.0,0.0)
(9.1,9.1,9.1,0.0)
(9.2,9.2,9.2,0.0)

Comment: how can i generalize the .map(t..) because  i do not know the number of columns in my data , so , it won't be possible to map it manually that what i meant

Comment: @MaherHTB Shankar's answer is accurate for the question you asked. You can accept that and create a new question about the other problem that you have.

Comment: try this resultatOfprediction.zip(parsedData)
    .map(t => t._1.productIterator.toList.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double]) :+ t._2)

Comment: thanks @RahulShukla that should work fine can i update in the answer ?

Comment: Sure @ShankarKoirala